# Print Wikipedia Article Title from Gensim WikiCorpus

Tags: python, nlp, wikipedia, gensim, text-analysis

I believe my question is easy, but I'm very new to python and I think that is blinding me a bit.

I've downloaded a Wikipedia dump as explained under "Preparing the Corpus" here: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html.  Then I ran the following lines of code:

```
import gensim

# these next two lines take around 16 hours
wikiDocs = gensim.corpora.wikicorpus.WikiCorpus('enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2')
gensim.corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('wiki_en_vocab200k', wikiDocs)
```

These lines of code are taken from the link above.  Now, in a separate script I've done some text analysis.  The result of that text analysis is a number representing the index of a particular article in the wikiDocs corpus.  The problem, I don't know how to print out the text of that article.  The obvious thing to try is:

```
wikiDocs[index_of_article]
```

but that returns the error

```
TypeError: 'WikiCorpus' object does not support indexing
```

I've tried a few other things but I'm stuck.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can often get a long way with `help(wikiCorpus)` which shows its docstring, if any, or `dir(wikiDocs)`, which shows the interface of the instance you made. Failing that, running in IPython, e.g. in Jupyter Notebook, gives you tab completion and other nifty tools for probing an object to find out what to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not actually such an easy quesion, the reason why it didn't work is that `WikiCorpus` isn't an iterator, it's just a class with a few functions for saving and loading. You can see the functions buy typing `WikiCorpus.` and pressing TAB into IPython (this shows the options for TAB-completion:

```
In [8]: wikiDocs = gensim.corpora.wikicorpus.WikiCorpus.
gensim.corpora.wikicorpus.WikiCorpus.get_texts    gensim.corpora.wikicorpus.WikiCorpus.load         gensim.corpora.wikicorpus.WikiCorpus.save_corpus
gensim.corpora.wikicorpus.WikiCorpus.getstream    gensim.corpora.wikicorpus.WikiCorpus.save
```

It looks like we want `get_texts`, this will probably return an iterator rather than a list though, (iterators don't directly support indexing either) so you'll have to use

```
list(wikidocs.get_texts())[i]
```

or

```
from itertools import islice
next(islice(wikidocs.get_texts(),i,i+1))
```

Comment: True. wikiDocs is not an array or list. Infact its an object of gensim defined class.